# How to log on console if there is some text in input?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to log to console `no text` if there is nothing in `input` and the opposite if there is some value present in it.

Here is my `HTML`:

```
<input id="myInput">text here</input>
<button id="myButton">pressMe</button>
```

Here is JavaScript Code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

var button = document.getElementById("myButton");

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {

  if (input !== null) {
    console.log("no text!")
  } else if(input === true || "") {
    console.log("text here!");
  }

}
```

Comment: Improved question statement, improved formatting and corrected question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tags are slightly wrong, should look like:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="Text here">
<button id="myButton">pressMe</button>
```

Code could be (to log to console on button press):

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  if(inputValue === ''){
     console.log('no value')
  } else{
     console.log('value of ' + inputValue + ' entered');
  }
});
```